# Is there a way to to close current taskpane in outlook web add-in?

Tags: javascript, xml, outlook-web-addins

I was wondering if there was a way to close a taskpane programmatically in an outlook web add-in.

I followed this link : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/show-hide-add-in

But `Office.addin.hide()` and `Office.addin.showAsTaskpane()` are not working.

Can someone help me?

Comment: Hey, as mentioned in the doc SharedRuntime is required to make it work. Can you please explain your scenario to help us better?

Note: As a workaround, you can use Office.context.ui.closeContainer() [Office.context.ui.closeContainer()] which is basically the same as closing the taskpane manually. There is no way in Outlook to "hide" the taskpane and have it still be running in the background.

Comment: I was trying to hide/close a taskpane. I didn't need it to run in background. I used Office.context.ui.closeContainer() and it worked wonderfully. Thank you! @OutlookAdd-insTeam-MSFT

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [Office.context.ui.closeContainer()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/office/office.ui?view=common-js-preview#office-office-ui-closecontainer-member(1)) which closes the UI container where the JavaScript is executing.

The behavior of this method is specified by the following:

- Called from a UI-less command button: No effect. Any dialog opened by `displayDialogAsync` will remain open.
- Called from a task pane: The task pane will close. Any dialog opened by `displayDialogAsync` will also close. If the task pane supports pinning and was pinned by the user, it will be un-pinned.

Answer (score 0):

@OutlookAdd-insTeam-MSFT answered my question.

You simply have to use: `Office.context.ui.closeContainer()`